#  undefined method `page' for #<Array:0xbc0ff98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, will-paginate

My Active admin version is 0.3.0, other than that m also using 'Will_paginate' i had made the configuration settings of conflict between kaminari and will_paginate but still m getting this error. i dont know where m making a mistake everything is working fine for other model but not for this model, need help, i have searched also found some links but not get satisfactory answer, it give me error on bold line

```
    ActiveAdmin.register User do
      menu :parent => 'Reports'

      filter :id
      filter :user_id
      filter :updated_at
# and other filters

      scope :all, :default => true do |user|
        User.all
      end
      scope :active do |user|
        User.where("user.status = ?", 'actvie')
      end
      scope :rejected do |user|
        User.where("user.status = ?", 'non_active')
      end

      actions :index, :show

      index do
        column "ID" do |u|
          link_to u.id, cs_user_path(u)
        end
        column "Status" do |u|
          status_tag(u.status)
        end
        column "User" do |u|
          link_to(u.user.full_name, cs_user_path(u.user)) rescue nil
        end
      end

      collection_action :index, :method => :get do
        scope = User.includes([:group,:address]).scoped
        scope = scope.order params[:order].gsub(/_/,' ') if params[:order]

        @collection = scope.paginate(:per_page => 25,:page => params[:page]) if params[:q].blank?
        @search = scope.metasearch(clean_search_params(params[:q]))

        **super do |format|**
          format.html {
            render "active_admin/resource/index"
          }
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: somebody please answer i have been stucked from last 2 hours

Comment: i have solved the problem, the problem is that, User.all return a array, and will_paginate not work on arrays, in order to solve it, simply replace User.all with User.order('id DESC') so that it would return active record relation, thanks for your apprecation

Answer (score 3):

The GitHub documentation of will_paginate states that arrays are not supported that well.

I will suggest using the kaminari gem which includes a helper method for array pagination.

You should be able to take it from here.